# Agrupar e somar colunas - r

Tags: r, dplyr

Dados:

```
P<-c("Alemanha", "USA", "Alemanha", "USA", "USA", "França")
Citacoes<-c(1,5,8,0,9,20)
df<-data.frame(P,Citacoes)
```

Sendo que cada `P` (país) representa 1 documento e cada documento tem uma quantidade de `Citacoes` (citações) associada a ele.

Preciso agrupar `P` e somar `Citações`.

O que consigo com o código abaixo:

```
     library(dplyr)
a<-
group_by(df,P)%>%
  summarise(Total=sum(Citacoes))
a
```

Mas além disso, também preciso apresentar, na mesma tabela, uma soma do número de documentos por país. No caso, `"USA"` tem três documentos, `"Alemanha"` tem dois documentos e `"França"` tem um.

Ou seja, no final preciso de uma tabela com 3 colunas `pais`, Total de `Citacoes` por `pais` associado e soma de documentos.

Por fim, gostaria de criar uma nova coluna com a média de `Citacoes` por `pais`, tentei o `mutate`, porém sem sucesso. E ordenar esses dados em ordem decrescente pelo número de documentos de cada país.

Estou aberto a tentar soluções além do `dplyr`.

Grato

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O código da pergunta está quase lá, basta incluir a contagem `n()`:

```
library(dplyr)

a <- df %>%
  group_by(P) %>%
  summarise(Total = sum(Citacoes),
            Count = n())
a
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  P        Total Count
#  <fct>    <dbl> <int>
#1 Alemanha     9     2
#2 França      20     1
#3 USA         14     3
```

Para também calcular as médias, basta incluir a fórmula de cálculo no `summarise`.

```
a <- df %>%
  group_by(P) %>%
  summarise(Total = sum(Citacoes),
            Count = n(),
            Media = Total/Count)
a
## A tibble: 3 x 4
#  P        Total Count Media
#  <fct>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>
#1 Alemanha     9     2  4.5 
#2 França      20     1 20   
#3 USA         14     3  4.67
```

Comment: Obrigado! 

E para criar uma coluna que seja a média de citacoes por pais? 
Tentei o mutate, mas não consegui. 

Por fim, seria interessante também ordenar pela quantidade da coluna Count...

Comment: @GustavoOliveiraPinto No `summarise`, basta incluir `Media = Total/Count`. Vou editar.

Comment: Rui, testei aqui dessa maneira e funcionou também:

a<-
  group_by(df,P)%>%
  summarise(Total=sum(Citacoes),
            Count = n())%>%
  mutate(razao = Total / Count)
a

b=a[order(a$Count,decreasing=T),]